# Jenkins crashing IE when trying to configure

Tags: internet-explorer, jenkins

I'm trying to configure system in Jenkins, but whenever I try to configure, IE stops working.  Other pages within Jenkins work though.  I tried removing Jenkins and reinstalling, but I still get the same problem

Here are some of the details from the crash
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: IEXPLORE.EXE
  Application Version:  10.0.9200.16866
  Application Timestamp:    53211297
  Fault Module Name:    MSHTML.dll

Comment: Can you post some details of the crash error ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried a browser that is not Internet Explorer? :)

Comment: Looks like it works in chrome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the current versions of Jenkins: [JENKINS-17825](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17825)

Known workarounds:

1. Use a different browser
2. Enable Compatibility Mode in IE